# Pair missing values between data frame and deduped data frame AND output to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a list of schools and their offered classes. I also have a list of unique classes, in which only some are offered at various schools, while some are not. I want to return the missing classes for each school, paired with the name of the school.

I am already able to return the list of missing classes for each school, however I am not able to pair and return the school name that corresponds to the missing class for each school.

## Read in dataframes

```
schools = {'School': ['School A', 'School A', 'School A', 'School B', 'School B', 'School B', 'School C','School C', 'School D'], 'Class': ['Math', 'Chemistry', 'English', 'Math', 'Chemistry', 'English', 'Math', 'Chemistry', 'Physics']}
dfSchool = pd.DataFrame(data=schools)
dfSchool

classes = {'Class': ['Math', 'Chemistry', 'English', 'History', 'Physics']}
dfClasses = pd.DataFrame(data=classes)
dfClasses
```

## Group by school

```
grouped = dfSchool.groupby('School')

newdflist = []

for name, group in grouped:
    newdflist.append(group)
    print(name)
    print(group)
```

## Return the missing classes for each school

```
i = 0
while i < 4:
    missingClasses = dfClasses[~dfClasses['Class'].isin(newdflist[i]['Class'])]
    print(missingClasses)
    i += 1
```

Actual Results:

```
     Class
3  History
4  Physics

     Class
3  History
4  Physics

     Class
2  English
3  History
4  Physics

       Class
0       Math
1  Chemistry
2    English
3    History
```

Desired Results:

```
  School    Class
3 School A  History
4 School A  Physics

  School    Class
3 School B  History
4 School B  Physics

  School    Class
2 School C  English
3 School C  History
4 School C  Physics

  School    Class
0 School D      Math
1 School D Chemistry
2 School D   English
3 School D   History
```

Answer (score 0):

a quick answer that prints the desired result is here:

```
    for name, group in grouped:
        print(name)
        print(dfClasses[~(dfClasses.Class.isin(group["Class"]))])
```

The result I get from this is:

```
   School A
    Class
    3 History
    4  Physics
   School B
    Class
    3 History
    4 Physics
   School C
    Class
    2 English
    3 History
    4 Physics
   School D
    Class
    0 Math
    1 Chemistry
    2 English
    3 History
```

What you have to do is just put it in a dataframe instead of printing.

Hope this helps 
:)

Comment: Now how would I output this result list to a csv file? I tried using the to_csv function but it only writes the data for School A to the csv file, not all schools to the csv file

Comment: You have to put it all into one dataframe. If you have it in several, you have to either merge them or print them to different files.

Comment: Ya that's exactly what I was thinking, however I am not sure how to put a for loop such as this into a single dataframe, since I do not want multiple dataframes in this case